# jQuery .click() not working on Android Lollipop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, web-applications

I'm having troubles using the `.click()` function for some stuff i need on a Cordova App.

The .click() function works very well on 4.x but doesn't on 5.x what i did for now is doing `href="javascript:function()"` but is not recommended using with CSP enabled.

How can i made the `.click()` function work on 5.x ?

The frameworks im using:

```
Apache Cordova 5.0
jQuery Mobile 1.4.5
jQuery 1.11
```

My Code:

```
<a href="javascript:chk('si');" class="chk chksi">Si</a>
<a href="javascript:chk('no');" class="chk chkno">No</a>
<div class="clear"></div>
<br /><br />
<a id="btnOk" href="javascript:btnOk();"><img src="img/registrar.png" class="center" width="75%"></a>
```

Old Code:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".chk").click(function() {
        $(".chk").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
   $("#btnOk").click(function() {
       //Stuff here
    });
   });
```

Thanks !

EDIT: Didn't added the `$(document).ready()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have this elsewhere, but this would be complete jquery for just those functions:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".chk").click(function() {
        $(".chk").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

    $("#btnOk").click(function() {
        //Stuff here
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, it's already inside a $(document).ready() function. Didn't post that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not well known, but to resolve it you can simply use touchend instead of click (the default). Just add an argument to each click event as follows:

```
$("#btnOk").click("touchend", function() {
```

If this does not work or you have further questions, please let me know.`